# Determining the values of $t > 0$ for which an integral converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to determine for which $t > 0$ the integral $I = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x^{2 - t}dx$ converges. Evidently $t \neq 3$, as the logarithm function is defined for $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$. Thus we have to consider $t \in (0, 3)$ and $t \in (3, \infty)$. If $t \in (3, \infty)$, then $I = \left[\frac{1}{x^{t - 3}\underbrace{(3 - t)}_{< 0}}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{(\infty)^{t - 3}(3 - t)}}_{ = 0} - \underbrace{\frac{1}{(-\infty)^{t - 3}(3 - t)}}_{ = 0} = 0$. But what happens with $t \in (0, 3)$? Then $I = \left[\frac{x^{3 - t}}{3 - t}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$. Is it so that if by the exponent $x^{3 - t}$ is an even function, then $I = 0$ and otherwise $I \to \infty$? How should this be examined?

Comment: It is $t$ or $p$ ? Is it $dt$ or $dx$ ? Also I don't think integrating on $\mathbb R^-$ is relevant, $x^{2-t}$ is not defined there for most of the reals $t$ ? (only on $\mathbb Q_{odd}$ the rationals with odd denominator).

Comment: @zwim My bad, I somehow messed up the description. The variable of interest is $t$ and it is $dx$.

Comment: The integral needs to be over $(0,\infty)$

Comment: The integral of a power function $\int_0^{\infty}x^p\,dx$ is never finite. Also, when you write $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$, you should clarify in which sense you're taking the limits (because the actual integral $\int_{\Bbb{R}}$ will never be absolutely convergent for such power functions). When dealing with power functions, one usually considers $\int_0^1$ or $\int_1^{\infty}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo What do you mean by "in which sense you're taking the limits"?

Comment: If I just wrote down $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\,dx$, what would you say the answer is?

Comment: @peek-a-boo That the integral diverges. Judging by your previous answer, is it so that even if the power of $x$ is even, the two limits don't cancel each other?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the power of $x$ is odd. But yes, the following "symmetric limit" $\lim_{r\to \infty}\int_{-r}^rx\,dx = 0$ is certainly true. But observe that $\lim_{r\to \infty}\int_{-r}^{2r}x\,dx = \infty$ and $\lim_{r\to \infty}\int_{-2r}^rx\,dx = -\infty$, and  really we can attain any value we want simply based on how we let the endpoints approach $\infty$. This happens precisely because the intergal doesn't converge absolutely (hence my remark above about specifying the sense in which the limit is taken). By the way, is this question from a textbook or is it your own?

Comment: @peek-a-boo The question is a small part of an assignment I am working on. So as a recap, the integral converges only when $t \in (3, \infty)$?

Comment: no, there is no value of $t$ for which the integral converges. For example, take $t=4$, then $x^{2-t}=\frac{1}{x^2}$, and this is not integrable near the origin; i.e $\int_0^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx = 0$ for every $\epsilon>0$. so certainly $\int_{\Bbb{R}}\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx = \infty$. If this is an assignment given by a professor, you should really clairfy with them what they had in mind, because as far as I can tell, this is a pretty silly question because the integral doesn't converge (in any reasonable sense) for any $t$.

Comment: The reason you find that the integral converges for $t>3$ is because you're ignoring the behavior near the origin, and only looking at the asymptotic behavior as $x\to \infty$. Of course, if your integral was something like $\int_{\{|x|>1\}}x^{2-t}\,dt$, then yes this integral will converge for all $t>3$, but for $t>3$, the problem is near the origin, while for $t<3$, the problem is near $\infty$. So, in every case the integral diverges (though for different reasons).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see. Well, you gave good pointers which I think answered my question. Do you think that should I now close this question?

Comment: I repeat it again, but integrating for $x<0$ makes no sense for $t$ real ($x^t$ undefined) ! So this discussion about integration on whole $\mathbb R$ is just pointless, unless $t$ is an integer (or at best a $\mathbb Q_{odd}$ rational).